# Checkbox filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to know how can I create a checkbox filter with a value of "no alcohol" so every time that is checked it will go through the array and select only the beers with the type "no alcohol"?

```js
var app = angular.module("myModule", []);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
  $scope.beer = [
    { name: "beer1",   price: 20, type:"Alcohol"},
    { name: "beer2",   price: 55, type:"no Alcohol" },
    { name: "beer3",   price: 20, type:"Alcohol" },
    { name: "beer4",   price: 37, type:"no Alcohol" },
    { name: "beer5", price: 20, type:"Alcohol" },
    { name: "beer6",  price: 32, type:"Alcohol" }
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="file:///C:/Users/LG/Documents/Angularteste/Teste/app.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" ng-model="test.name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="test.type">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="exactMatch"/> Exact Match
      </form>
      <ul ng-repeat="friend in beer | filter:test:exactMatch">
        <li>{{friend.name}}</li>
        <li>{{friend.type}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model='search.type1' ng-true-value="no alcohol" ng-false-value='' /> Would you like beer with no alchol? 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had error in template:
instead of

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model='search.type1' ng-true-value="no alcohol" ng-false-value='' /> Would you like beer with no alchol?
```

you need to change `search.type1` to `search.type` and `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` accepts expression not string, so you need to change it to:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.type" ng-true-value="'no Alcohol'" ng-false-value="''" /> Would you like beer with no alchol?
```

Last step is to add additional filter

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in beer | filter:test:exactMatch | filter:search:true">
```

Here's working snippet

```js
var app = angular.module("myModule", []);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
  $scope.beer = [
    { name: "beer1",   price: 20, type:"Alcohol"},
    { name: "beer2",   price: 55, type:"no Alcohol" },
    { name: "beer3",   price: 20, type:"Alcohol" },
    { name: "beer4",   price: 37, type:"no Alcohol" },
    { name: "beer5", price: 20, type:"Alcohol" },
    { name: "beer6",  price: 32, type:"Alcohol" }
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="file:///C:/Users/LG/Documents/Angularteste/Teste/app.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" ng-model="test.name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="test.type">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="exactMatch"/> Exact Match
      </form>
      <ul ng-repeat="friend in beer | filter:test:exactMatch | filter:search">
        <li>{{friend.name}}</li>
        <li>{{friend.type}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.type" ng-true-value="'no Alcohol'" ng-false-value="''" /> Would you like beer with no alchol? 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify custom methods as filter :

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in beer | filter:myCustomFilter">
        <li>{{friend.name}}</li>
        <li>{{friend.type}}</li>
</ul>
```

and in the controller :

```
$scope.myCustomFilter = function(el) {
    if(search.type1) {
        return el.type === "no Alcohol";
    }
    return true;
}
```